# Call Jquery Method inside Component Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular

I need to call a Jquery method inside an angular component, this is the scenario:

I want to use Materialize CSS framework toast feature:

eg:

```
Materialize.toast('toast content', 3000);
```

I tried to do like that:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  $(this.elementRef.nativeElement.Materialize.toast('toast content', 3000));
}
```

My console output is:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toast' of undefined
```

Comment: I don't know `Materialize`. Why do you think the element has a `Materialize`  property?

Comment: Because I imported the materialize.min.js into the index.html file, is it wrong?

Comment: From the docs it looks like just `Materialize.toast('toast content', 3000);` should do it

Comment: it gives me a compilation error on the Atom IDE when I try that

Comment: What does the error say?

Comment: but yea, the css aint working, but the message is showing, even with the IDE error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100506/discussion-between-marcos-j-c-kichel-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you must

```
class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    $(this._elementRef.nativeElement)...
  }
}
```

You might also need to disable view encapsulation

```
@Component({
  selector: 'zippy',
  templateUrl: 'zippy.html',
  styles: [`
    .zippy {
      background: green;
    }
  `],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

For more details see http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/06/29/shadow-dom-strategies-in-angular2.html

You should be aware that direct DOM access is discouraged in Angular2 because it prevents running in web worker and server rendering.
Also issues with are to be expected using jQuery.

Comment: Would it be better to put the jQuery call in `ngAfterViewInit()`?

Comment: Thanks guys, but in this special case it aint working, I am updating the question with more details ok?

Comment: Edited with more details